# Default label in FlowPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a FlowPane with many BorderPanes as windows. I would like to display something like water mark or label `<empty>` when the FlowPane is empty.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this:

```
FlowPane flowPane = ... ;

StackPane container = new StackPane();
Label placeHolder = new Label("No content in flow pane");
placeHolder.visibleProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(flowPane.getChildren()));
container.getChildren().addAll(flowPane, placeHolder);
```

Then, obviously, just add the container into your UI where you previously added the flow pane.